# excel enter dates with or without slashes

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have VBA code to convert a 6-digit number to a date with slashes i.e. 311215 becomes 31/12/2015 but I would also like the users to be able to enter a date with the slashes as well.

Using the code below, 31/12/15 becomes 23/04/1969 and 01/01/15 becomes 20/04/2005 (?? - answers on a postcard for that one).

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim StrVal As String
Dim dDate As Date

If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Intersect(target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With target

    StrVal = Format(.Text, "000000")

      If IsNumeric(StrVal) And Len(StrVal) = 6 Then

         Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 1 Then 'dd/mm/yy

            dDate = DateValue(Left(StrVal, 2) & "/" & Mid(StrVal, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(StrVal, 2))

        Else 'mm/dd/yy

            dDate = DateValue(Mid(StrVal, 3, 2) & "/" & Left(StrVal, 2) & "/" & Right(StrVal, 2))

        End If

        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

        .Value = CDate(DateSerial(Year(dDate), Month(dDate), Day(dDate)))

      End If

End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I also need to include validation so that only a date is entered in the cell as this is used in a number of other subs

Answer (score 0):

Your string `31/12/15` is evaluated as date and converted by `Format(.Text, "000000")` to the internal integer representation `42369` (which is the count of days since 1900). Your `Format` command does not remove the slashes but interprets the value as integer string. After that your code transforms this number to `23/04/1969`.

You could try to replace your

`StrVal = Format(.Text, "000000")`

by

`StrVal = Replace(.Text, "/", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that **D7** has been formatted as **Text before** any user entries:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim StrVal As String
    Dim dDate As Date

    If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With target
        StrVal = .Text
        If IsNumeric(StrVal) And Len(StrVal) = 6 Then
            If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 1 Then 'dd/mm/yy
                dDate = DateValue(Left(StrVal, 2) & "/" & Mid(StrVal, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(StrVal, 2))
            Else 'mm/dd/yy
                dDate = DateValue(Mid(StrVal, 3, 2) & "/" & Left(StrVal, 2) & "/" & Right(StrVal, 2))
            End If
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Value = dDate
        Else
            ary = Split(StrVal, "/")

            If Len(ary(2)) = 2 Then ary(2) = "20" & ary(2) 'fix the year if necessary

            If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 1 Then 'dd/mm/yy
                dDate = DateValue(ary(2) & "/" & ary(1) & "/" & ary(0))
            Else 'mm/dd/yy
                dDate = DateValue(ary(2) & "/" & ary(0) & "/" & ary(1))
            End If
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Value = dDate
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```